# Laravel 8 Customize bootstrap --auth Connection (ElasticSearch)

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-8

I am using elasticsearch on my laravel 8 project and my user table on elasticsearch to. I use composer require laravel/ui and php artisan ui bootstrap --auth Okay, everythink look good but how can I connect elasticsearch and verify user and authorization.

Normally, I connect with curl. For example:

```
        $hosts = ['localhost:9200'];
        $client = ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts($hosts)->build();

        $params = [
            'size' => 10000,
            'from' => 0,
            'index' => 'users',
            'type' => 'text',
            'body' => [
                'query' => [
                    'match_all' => new \stdClass(),
                ],
            ],
        ];

        $results = $client->search($params);

        $data = [];
        foreach ($results['hits']['hits'] as $hit) {
            $temp = [];
            $source = $hit['_source'];

            $temp = [
                'id' => $hit['_id'],
                'userName' => $source['userName'],
                'userRole' => $source['userRole'],
                'userPassword' => $source['userPassword'],
            ];

            $data[] = $temp;
        }

        return DataTables::of($data)->make(true);
```

This how can I fill my users table.